# Form occaisionally generating 404 page on submission

Tags: html, forms, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I've got a form that has 2 required fields (email and message) and 2 non-required fields (name and number).  It submits fine when you only fill out the required fields, but when the non-required fields are submitted it generates a 404.  I'm using wordpress if that's of any relevance.

```
<form id="question" action="thankyou" method="post">
    <p class="question-label">Type your email address here...</p>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text"></input>

    <h3>Your Question...</h3>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="GO" />

    <p>If you would like us to call you please enter you Name and Contact Number here:</p>

    <p class="question-label">Name</p>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"></input>

    <p class="question-label">Contact Number</p>
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's a 404, and not a blank page?

Comment: Yes, the page is generating the 404 error page.

Comment: A for-realsies 404? With the HTTP header stating 404?  Reason why I'm asking is because if it's not a 404 - and it's a blank page - it could be triggered by your form processor echoing something before all headers are sent, thus breaking the flow.  Try changing the action to "?" instead of "#".

Comment: Sorry - the code wasn't up to date.  It goes to a separate page not '#'.  Have updated.

Comment: Ah. Just a quick suggestion, you may want to put a more absolute URL there; ex: /thankyou/ (assuming it's a custom page.) Reason being is that WP will redirect from nearest-to exact page, and it may lose data in the process or choke up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's because you're using a reserved keyword for the 'name' input.  Try:

```
<input id="enq-name" name="enq-name" type="text"></input>
```

and it should fix your issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no reserved keywords for the ID and NAME attributes in HTML.

Comment: That is true, but they are reserved keywords when processing the form.

Comment: Here is the list of Reserved Terms for WordPress and "Name" is listed there http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms